# Making iron tools from blood

Tags: biology, hard-science, chemistry, metals, metalworking

So, I read a while ago several threads about making iron objects/blades from blood. In my conworld there are giant predators that would, according to my calculations, have enough blood so that 12 of them would make a decently sized sword (though that was counting the organs and all — would go up to 24 with just haemoglobin). This would mean that regular/anniversary hunts for such giants could lead to enough blood being stored for a royal (or very high born) person to have a sword forged for when they become an adult. I'm going off the basis that they are made aware by someone that there is iron in blood but that this person doesn't really influence their tech at all.

So the question is: how would you go about — with a people that barely are at the iron age — extracting iron from blood? I understand you would have to boil off the liquids from the blood and then turn it to ash but if I understood correctly the most tricky part is to decompose the haemoglobin and release the iron. So, with as much precision as possible, what process would be needed to properly extract the iron in order to make it into workable slugs? Would simply heating it all up degrade the haemoglobin enough or not?

Agrajag commented that centrifuging the ash and then recovering what is at the very bottom would give what I assume to be iron oxide (since they then advised that chemically reducing the powder would be needed, adding it needed to be mixed with equal part powdered natural graphite or ground charcoal and heat in the absence of an air flow). So: how hot would it need to burn to get the right type of ashes? How fast would it need to spin to get the iron to fall? And could this be replaced by some sort of decantation? And finally, is it needed to have graphite/charcoal, especially in equal parts, or is it like iron oxide/ore where you'd need at least a bloomery if not an actual blast furnace to change it to workable iron? And so would any kind of fuel work? I'm thinking of bamboo being used for wootz/damascus steel.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any references to these threads? Iron concentration in human blood is very small - about 1 mg per liter. You'd need a million liters of blood to extract 1 kilogram of iron.

Comment: Spilling blood into a fire sounds like a step towards inventing [black pudding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pudding), not a new metal source. It isn't obvious that it is even _possible_ to extract pure metal using ancient techniques from so much dross without a decent amount of chemistry to purify things first.

Comment: This question has inspired me to make some crazy tyrant that has made a sword forged from "blood iron" 'donated' from his enemies.

Comment: The average human has about 3.5 to 4 grams of iron in their blood. A Roman short sword weighs 700 to 1000 grams...

Comment: @Alexander this thread talks about iron in the blood and in the body. I may have over-estimated iron content though as I apparently assumed 0.8 g/L which… seems to not be the case. More like 0.4 g/L. Anyways. https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3q1oj5/how_much_iron_and_dust_is_in_the_human_body_on/

Comment: As for @AlexP, apparently it's also in the liver and all and my creatures are half the size of humans so their swords are ~400g and we have beasts with 43 litres of blood. I guess they'd actually need more like 24 of them…

Comment: @Nierninwa I was wrong in my calculations because I used [Serum iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serum_iron) figures which do not include hemoglobin.

Comment: VTR: the edits make the question a worldbuilding question.  Especially since we're focusing on an iron-age civilization.

Comment: Agree with JBH, the edits to clarify the question make it definitely on topic now (and a very interesting question). You could still trim off a little fat to make it easier to read (really all the  story-specific context you need is "I have an iron age civilization who was taught how to make weapons from the iron in giant blood") but I'm a critical offender in that regard myself, so can hardly judge, lol. Thanks for the fix +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

## [Alchemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemy).

The royal alchemist, in his time away from trying to reproduce [Greek Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire) or trying to find the secret of immortality, was following orders of the King in trying to create gold from base metals and materials.

They reasoned that blood had special properties of giving life (if you lose all yours you die) and must be, in some fundimental way powerfull - maybe it could hold the secret.

So, very much the way [phosphorous was discovere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus#Discovery)d (by mucking around with quantities of urine), the alchemists, seeking the [phillosopher's stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher%27s_stone) discovered iron in blood.

The process goes something like this (a chemist is welcome to correct this):

- Boil the liquid off the blood.
- Burn the residue to ash.
- Mix the ash with water and spin very fast (see [centrifuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge)).
- Collect the solid residue *at the very bottom* of the stuff that's in the bottom of your flask.
- Chemically reduce (mix with equal part powdered natural graphite or ground charcoal and heat in the absence of an air flow).

When you cool this powdered mixture you should be left with something that can be separated out into good and slag using a [lodestone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodestone). Then it should be just a question of hammering it into a workable slug (see [cold-welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding)).

This could indeed indirectly result in the alchemist recieving gold and becoming immortal in reputation, so partial success at least.

Comment: That's an interesting idea! Although I am not sure how advanced they would be and how much of an idea of alchemy they would have… but why not!

Answer (score 2):

No it would not

you have several problems

1. you will need gallons of blood to make anything describable as a nugget.
2. higher oxygen concentrations will work against you since it means the blood needs less hemoglobin.
3. 1200C is to low to smelt iron, you need something closer to 1600c. At 1200c iron is not even enough to forge iron much less smelt it.
4. putting blood on a hot rock and burning off the water will make a sludge reminiscent of crude oil, heating it further will produce ash, and that's if you managed to collect it the evaporating blood will be energetic enough to scatter the few stable contents those temperatures are high enough to get the leidenfrost effect.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I mean, then again, I'm most likely to stay around 22% so that wouldn't be a huge difference to now.
Also, I guess accidental discovery by dropping blood on a fire wouldn't work. And sure, you would need a lot. I'd need something like 43 litres for 35 grams. But maybe some accident a smith would have could clue them in? Again, I'm not clear on the *specific* processes needed to recover iron from blood.

Comment: keep in mind scholars figured out there was iron in blood only in the 1700's by analysing blood ash. so basically you are out of luck until about the same time they invent a steam engine. The iron in blood is just too scarce and hard to get at compared to what else is ino it. Basically people need to already be investigating chemistry.

Comment: On the other-hand people did stupid things to swords for various superstitious reasons since forever, they will not get any iron but you can easily have them dipping the swords in the blood for mystical reasons. Real humans did things equally pointless.

Comment: It doesn't have the same… importance to it though. Having to hunt down THIRTEEN massive predators is an idea I liked…